# Viewing images uploaded to Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django admin page that uploads images to a product description. Everything works until I try to view the image by clicking on its path in the products information. I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:6666/the_image.jpg
```

I'm guessing I need to declare something in urls.py, but I have no idea where to start. I also tried changing my media paths in settings.py but I always get errors if I change to anything other than '/'

model.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/')
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/'
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

admin.py

```
class InlineImage(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineImage]
```

Comment: Are you just using the django dev server?  Do you have urls.py setup to serve static files?

Comment: I think I am using the dev server... "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6666" is what I use to start it. And, no, I do not, I will look into that now.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-files
and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles

Comment: Actually uploaded files go to MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL static is for things like assets JS/CSS/Images

Comment: Ok, so what would I put in urls.py to make my files accessible through the server? assuming that I had something like...
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/name/files/app/media"
MEDIA_URL = "/media"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs are here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root

You need to set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your settings file like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = /var/www/example.com/media/
MEDIA_URL = /media
```

and your upload_to should probably be the model name or something to identify it.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
```

Then the link should point the /media/image/NAME_OF_IMAGE.png

You will also need to have urls.py setup to server media files.  For production you would want to do this in nginx with an alias.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Which says:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just finished the Django tutorial. Going beyond it there are so many tiny details to get right it can be a little overwhelming.... Also, if you don't mind, how would this set-up change once I move my app over to a an actual server?

Comment: I would recommend uwsgi and nginx.  uwsgi can be a bit overwhelming but it is really good to work with.  There is a tutorial here http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html  and the example nginx config has aliases for media and static